# Horizontal align items Slick Carousel

Tags: jquery, html, css, slick.js

The problem is I'm using Slick Carousel but whenever I add the div to Slick's script I'm using the content moves into a different line.

How it should look.
[image: How it should look]

This is what happens as soon as I add the scroll div to Slick script.

[image: Slick result]

I'm almost sure it's a CSS problem but I've tried a lot and can't get it to work. This is my code...

```
<div class="testimonios">
        <div class="testimonios__container">
            <p id="title">Testimonios</p>
            <div class="testimonios__container-scroll">

                <div class="testimonios__container-photo">
                    <img id="photo" src="img/photo.png">
                    <p id="message"><b> Edoardo Perez - Nucliux. </b><br><br>“Humanus logró que mi empresa encontrara los mejores candidatos para satisfacer mis necesidades”. </p>
                </div>

                <!--<div class="testimonios__container-photo">
                    <img id="photo" src="img/photo.png">
                    <p id="message"><b> Alan Vázquez - Nucliux. </b><br><br>"Humanus me encanta" </p>
                </div> -->

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Slick

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $('.testimonios__container-scroll').slick({
            autoplay: true,
            autoplaySpeed: 2000,
            infinite: true,
            pauseOnHover: false,

          });
        });
    </script>
```

This is the related CSS

```
.testimonios{
    height: 23vw;
    background: url("../img/testimonios.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.testimonios__container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    height: 20vw;
}

.testimonios__container-scroll{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 70%;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 15%;
}

#photo{
    margin-right: 3vw;
    width: auto;
    height: 10vw;
}

.testimonios__container-photo{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: ;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10vw;
    margin-left: ;
}

#title{
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.5vw;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 2.2vw;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 1.5vw;
}


#message{
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.2vw;
    margin-top: 1vw;
    margin-bottom: 1vw;
}
```

There is a Live Demo [here](http://nucliux.mx/humanus/) scroll to bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slick slider is changin the display type of the container you are pointing which you need as flex.
put a wrapper around thzt container and initialize slick on that

```
<div class="testimonios">
    <div class="testimonios__container">
        <p id="title">Testimonios</p>
        <div class="slickz">
           <div>
             <div class="testimonios__container-scroll">
                  <div class="testimonios__container-photo">
                      <img id="photo" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d3/User_Circle.png">
                      <p id="message"><b> Edoardo Perez - Nucliux. </b><br><br>“Humanus logró que mi empresa encontrara los mejores candidatos para satisfacer mis necesidades”. </p>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div>
             <div class="testimonios__container-scroll">
                  <div class="testimonios__container-photo">
                      <img id="photo" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d3/User_Circle.png">
                      <p id="message"><b> Edoardo Perez - Nucliux. </b><br><br>“Humanus logró que mi empresa encontrara los mejores candidatos para satisfacer mis necesidades”. </p>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div>
             <div class="testimonios__container-scroll">
                  <div class="testimonios__container-photo">
                      <img id="photo" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d3/User_Circle.png">
                      <p id="message"><b> Edoardo Perez - Nucliux. </b><br><br>“Humanus logró que mi empresa encontrara los mejores candidatos para satisfacer mis necesidades”. </p>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div>
             <div class="testimonios__container-scroll">
                  <div class="testimonios__container-photo">
                      <img id="photo" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d3/User_Circle.png">
                      <p id="message"><b> Edoardo Perez - Nucliux. </b><br><br>“Humanus logró que mi empresa encontrara los mejores candidatos para satisfacer mis necesidades”. </p>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $('.slickz').slick({
            autoplay: true,
            autoplaySpeed: 2000,
            infinite: true,
            pauseOnHover: false,

          });
        });
    </script>
```

notice the div wrapping each `.testimonios__container-scroll`
fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/woptima/Lj5pwdhp/2/

Comment: It stayed on position yes but uncomment what is the 2nd element and it breaks, not sure why it also doesn't animate.

Comment: it is the same problem here is fiddle with multiple slides: https://jsfiddle.net/woptima/Lj5pwdhp/2/

Comment: Ohh yes! Thanks! I can see it works now. Any idea why on the last element the style disappears for a few seconds and then it goes back to original?

Comment: Thats the 'inifite loop' which create a copy of first div and messes up the styling. Probably because you are using flex inside each slide. I would use a solution without flex, using inline blocks and set widths. example: set image to width: 100px;, and message to width: calc(100% - 100px) and make them both inline.